# Undefined variable $services, error in Laravel 9

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-9

**Controller**

```
public function index()
{
    $services = Services::all();

    return view('/dashboard', compact('home'));
}
```

And this is the blade file that shows an error.

```
@foreach($services as $service)
    <!--Cards-->
    <div class="row d-flex justify-content-evenly my-5" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-duration="1000">
        <!--Card 1-->
        <div class="card my-3" style="width: 18rem;">
            <img src={{ $services->image }} class="card-img-top" alt="...">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">{{ $services->name }}</h5>
                <p class="card-text">{{ $services->description }}</p>
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-evenly ">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary fw-bold">AVAIL</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa-sharp fa-solid fa-cart-shopping"><a
                                    href="{{ route('add.to.cart', $product->id) }}"> Add to Cart</i>
                        </a></button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
@endforeach
```

I want to display the data under the `$services` variable, but it shows an error that the `$services` variable is not defined.

Comment: `compact('home')` but you named your variable `$services`...

Answer (score 0):

You haven't passed `$services` [to the view](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/views#passing-data-to-views).

```
return view('dashboard')->with('services', $services);
```